# Using a c++ dll in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

If I have some c# code like this

```
   public const string CppFunctionsDLL = @"..\..\..\Release\CplusplusCode.dll";

    [DllImport(CppFunctionsDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int GetData(out IntPtr data, byte[] dataFromCard);
```

After building the solution..then running the executable on a different machine.. when `GetData` gets called does the actual c++ dll have to be present on the machine the executable is running on? or was everything loaded in when the build of the solution was run..?

Essentially.. how do I ensure that when the executable is run on a users machine.. that the c++ dll is present and that I can reference it in code?

Comment: *or was everything loaded in when the build of the solution was run..?*  In the context that you are asking the question, the answer is **no**.  That's not how it works.

Comment: @Eljay how do I ensure that when the executable is run on a users machine.. that the c++ dll is present and that I can reference it in code? Or am I completely misunderstanding things.. ?

Comment: @the1.9gpaProgrammer Include it in the zip file or distribute it using one of the many installer programs available.

Comment: And get that long relative path out of the `DllImport` arguments.... no user is going to want their installation layout to match your Visual Studio build tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when GetData gets called does the actual c++ dll have to be present on the machine the executable is running on?

Yes.  `DllImport` works internally by using [`LoadLibrary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw) and [`GetProcAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) at runtime. When the C# function is called, the referenced DLL is loaded, and then the referenced DLL function is called, marshaling parameter data back and forth as needed.

> or was everything loaded in when the build of the solution was run..?

No.

> Essentially.. how do I ensure that when the executable is run on a users machine.. that the c++ dll is present and that I can reference it in code?

You must distribute and install the DLL alongside the built EXE.  How you do that exactly is up to you.  There are many ways to bundle up and distribute multi-file applications.  For example, via a [Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal) MSI package.